# Como pedir objeto IMAGEN a la etiqueta IMG

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

como estan ? Les cuento, estoy aprendiendo JQuery y necesito pedir el objeto imagen para subirlo al storage de firebase. Yo tengo lo siguiente:

```
$$('#i1').attr('src', imgData);
```

el cual me pone en una ventanita la imagen que seleccione de la galeria o que saque con la camara. Ahora, yo necesito pedirle a ese id #i1 el objeto imagen para subirlo a el storage de firebase, como haria? Probe con:

```
$$('#1').html();
$$('#1').getElementByID();
```

y no me devuelve el objeto imagen, alguno me daria una mano? Gracias

Comment: ¿A qué llamas tú el *objeto imagen*? ¿Podrías poner un trozo de HTML indicando qué es lo que quieres sacar?

Answer (score 0):

si lo que quieres es obtener el "archivos" lo que tienes que hacer es obtener ese elemento desde el objeto de HTML seleccionado, la orden te devolverá un arreglo por lo que tienes que elegir el primer objeto de este en la posición 0:

```
    var file_data = $('#1').prop('files')[0];
```

Te recomiendo ampliamente que no utilices como ids o classes números ya que es muy difícil para el mantenimiento de tu programa el referirse a objetos sin la semántica apropiada.